# MySQL Custom Order

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I have a table that I select data from with a column called parent that's of unsigned integer type.

It has numbers from 0 to 12.

I want to `select *` from table order by parent asc, but with one exception: place the 0 at the end of the select so it would be like `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0`.

Is this possible with a single select in MySQL please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
select * 
from your_table 
order by (parent != 0) desc, parent asc;
```

Comment: `select * from your_table order by parent=0, parent;`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from table 
order by case when parent is 0 then 1 else 0 end, 
    parent asc
```